# CQLSH: How to print text on execution of >source 'CommandFile';

Tags: command-line, cassandra, cqlsh

I am using these functionalities:

```
Linux>cqlsh
cqlsh>use mydatabase;
cqlsh:mydatabase>source 'myCommands.cqlsh';
...
cqlsh:mydatabase>
```

Since I am executing a file, I wish to comment some outputs,  I would like to find a way to print a sort of `echo ''` or `print "hello";` on the output.  Is it possible ?

Comment: @WorkingHard, in MySQL, doing `mysql> select "world" AS Hello;` does the job. I am looking for something similar in cqlsh>.

Answer (score 1):

You could just script this out, piping your split CQL scripts to cqlsh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "SOURCE 'myCommands1.cql'" | cqlsh
echo "hello"
echo "SOURCE 'myCommands2.cql'" | cqlsh
echo "done.."
```

Comment: Hum... referring to the snippet, the `echo` looked for is within the cqlsh console output.  You are suggesting `echo` from a standard *nux shell command which is not what I wish for.